# How to safely and portably create temp file AND get its name

Tags: c, io, temp

I'm working with some legacy code which passes around the name of a file. I'd like to create a temp file and give the legacy code the name of the file to be opened later using legacy functions. `tmpnam` is unsafe due to the race case between getting the name and creating the file. `mkdir` isn't portable to Windows and doesn't let me have the name of the file. How can I create a temp file safely, portably, and with retention of file name?

Comment: Define your portability requirements.  The standard C library has nothing to offer.  If you need portability between Windows and non-Windows, you're going to need to define a portable interface to non-portable implementations of the function(s) — what you do on Windows will be different in detail from what you do on Unix.  I'm not clear the `mkdir()` is necessary; you can simply demand that the directory be already created.

Comment: I wrote a Unix-based set of functions: `extern void tfn_setdirectory(const char *dir);
extern void tfn_setprefix(const char *pfx);
extern int  tfn_tempfilename(const char *sfx, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz);
extern int  tfn_tempdirname(const char *sfx, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz);` to cover a portability problem between different variants of Unix. It could be used as a basis for a Windows and Unix variant. It uses two 32-bit random numbers as part of the name — and you can control the directory and file suffix. It uses a sequence of environment variables to find the default directory.

Comment: Shout if you would like the code — either by comment `@Jonathan` or see my profile.

Answer (score 0):

In windows  `GetTempFileName` function. In Linux if you do not more than 25 files (bug in some implementations) `mkstemp` family of functions or `tmpfile`